# Open/Free Area Code shapefiles for the US/Canada

Tags: shapefile, data

I would like to map magicJack's areacodes and exchanges against known area codes and exchanges to create a coverage map, just to see what it would look like as compared with, say, a mobile phone coverage map.

Having read this previous post:
[Shapefiles for U.S. Area Codes (NANP)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/shapefiles-for-u-s-area-codes-nanp)
I see the only available databases seem to cost more than I'm willing to pay. And the maxmind information is point data rather than polygon data. I'm curious if any new free/open resources have become available since the previous posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I recently plotted out US area codes. I found the shapefile from https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f4e4a19e4b07f02db605716 . Partial screen capture below.

[image]

I was only interested in US codes so I loaded the files into http://www.mapshaper.org/ and filtered out the Candada boundaries.

[image]

Late answer but hopefully this helps someone just starting out with shapefiles (like me!)